# @XmlElement and @JsonProperty together in same pojo

Tags: json, jaxb

I want to map json property and xml element using same pojo with custom name. Below is my request body structure:
For XML:

```
<TEST_REQUEST>
<CITY_NAME>abc</CITY_NAME>
<STATE_NAME>xyz</STATE_NAME>
</TEST_REQUEST>
```

For Json: {"cityName": "abc", "stateName": "xyz"}
I used below code, but it's not working. Can anybody please suggest what's wrong in this code, Thanks in advance

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "TEST_REQUEST")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class TestRequest {

      @XmlElement(name = "CITY_NAME")
      @JsonProperty(value = "cityName")
      private String city;

      @JsonProperty(value = "stateName")
      @XmlElement(name = "STATE_NAME")
      private String state;

      public String getCity() {
        return city;
      }

      public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
      }

      public String getState() {
        return state;
      }

      public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: it works if you use jackson directly. how do you generate JSON ? via ? And "not working" is clearly not teling anything about the error.

Comment: @Ulab If request is hit with xml payload, values are populated in the respective properties of POJO perfectly but with with json payload, it doen't set the respective properties. In case of JSON it throws error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "city" (class com.apple.ist.aconline.qpmigration.qpws.entity.request.TestRequest), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "CITY_NAME", "STATE_NAME"]). But this scenario also works fine if the json payload is changed to {"CITY_NAME": "abc", "STATE_NAME": "xyz"}

Comment: Unrecognized field "city" is not same as  "cityName". Is that typo error ? you will have to use "cityName" as mentioned in the property.

Comment: @Ulab Sorry for the wrong error I pasted, this is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyExcep‌​tion: Unrecognized field "cityName" (class com.apple.ist.aconline.qpmigration.qpws.entity.request.TestR‌​equest), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "CITY_NAME", "STATE_NAME"]).

Comment: are you using API like `REST` ? because if you use just ObjectMapper.readValue(), it works perfectly with direct serialization/deserialization of `jackson-json` So the problem is in the underlying API (?) that you use which you will have to explain.

Comment: Yes I am using JAX-RS with RestEasy implementation, this is my test controller to read the request payload 

@Path("/rest")
public class TestController {
    @POST
    @Path("/testdata")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response readRequestPayload(final TestRequest restRequest) {
      return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
    }
}

Comment: I resolved the issue using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty annotation in place of org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty and that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue using com.**fasterxml**.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty annotation in place of org.**codehaus**.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty and that worked for me. Thanks